# How can I copy Growl output to the clipboard?

Tags: macos, mac, clipboard, growl

Is there any way I can copy Growl notifications to the clipboard, or store them to a file?

If I get a notification I'd like to be able to do something like right click it and choose "copy to clipboard" or maybe set up a log file that would contain the text that I could then copy.

[image: Screen shot 2012-03-28 at 12.21.23 PM.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest MAS version of Growl does support a history feature as well as rollup. The actual log files can be access from the history tab in Growl. Haven't tried copying to the clipboard but is possibly the closest you will get to this functionality.

[image: Growl History]

I also found this [article](http://gthing.net/enable-growl-log-and-show-it-in-geektool) explaining how to enable a Growl log file to display using GeekTool:

> touch ~/Library/Logs/Growl.log
>   defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp GrowlLoggingEnabled -bool YES
>   defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp GrowlLogType 1
>   defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp "Custom log history 1"   /Users/kent/Library/Logs/Growl.log

Comment: looks good. i don't know what growl's limit is for message size in this version, but it appears to be pretty small. wish it was bigger and this would be perfect. thanks